# How to superimpose two MATLAB images rigidly transformed to perform a metrics

Tags: machine-learning, matlab, similarities, image-processing

I got two MRI images on MATLAB, I need to perform an intensity based registration similarity metrics in order to get a registration. The problem is that, since I got some rigid transformation on one (translation and rotation), I got really confused how to do the correspondence between pixels.

Should I use some kind of interpolation to decide the couples of pixel to confront in the two images?

Answer (score 1):

Ok so assuming you have a rigid matrix (4x4 affine matrix for 3d images) you can relate the voxels before and after the registration as follows:

```
[p_X,p_Y,p_Z] =meshgrid(1:size(MRI,2),1:size(MRI,1),1:size(MRI,3));
after_p_X=p_X.*M(1,1)+p_Y.*M(1,2)+p_Z.*M(1,3)+M(1,4);
after_p_Y=p_X.*M(2,1)+p_Y.*M(2,2)+p_Z.*M(2,3)+M(2,4);
after_p_Z=p_X.*M(3,1)+p_Y.*M(3,2)+p_Z.*M(3,3)+M(3,4);
```

then you need to perform a interpolation to get the new intensities.

```
new_MRI =interp3(p_X,p_Y,p_Z,MRI,after_p_X,after_p_Y,after_p_Z,'cubic');
```